# How to perform $regex on "_id" in official mongodb golang package?

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm trying to perform regex query on ObjectId() in golang "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/" package.

I tried so far:

```
query := bson.M{}
query["_id"] = primitive.Regex{
    Pattern: mySearchID,
    Options: "i",
}
opts := options.Find()
collection.Find(context.TODO(), query, opts)
```

It doesn't work at all.

I tried also:

```
query := bson.M{}
query["_id"] = bson.D{
    {
        Key:   "$regex",
        Value: mySearchID,
    },
    {
        // i is for case insensitive
        Key:   "$options",
        Value: "i",
    },
}
opts := options.Find()
collection.Find(context.TODO(), query, opts)
```

It also doesn't work.

How can I find documents with just part of the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$regex most likely only works on strings. If you look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/ the word "string" is italicized:

> Provides regular expression capabilities for pattern matching *strings* in queries.

So:

```
irb(main):034:0> a['foo'].find.first
=> {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('6068e59d4896683bab61ddbe'), "test"=>1}

irb(main):035:0> a['foo'].find(_id: /606/).first
=> nil
```

You can use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/ (and an aggregation pipeline) to convert the values to the string type:

```
irb(main):037:0> a['foo'].aggregate([{'$set'=>{_id:{'$convert'=>{input:'$_id',to:'string'}}}},{'$match':{_id:/606/}}
]).to_a
=> [{"_id"=>"6068e59d4896683bab61ddbe", "test"=>1}]
```

Note that this type converts the _id to a string, if you need it in its original ObjectId type you'll need to $convert back.

Comment: Is it possible to use $convert outside aggregation framework?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.

Comment: But you can probably use $gt etc. for range queries.